# Remove first comma from a csv file in bash

Tags: bash, csv

I have a csv file in which some lines start with a comma, so I want to remove all of them.

Example: In this line: `,"a","b","c"`, I want to remove the first comma.

How do I do this in bash?

Comment: `sed -i '' 's/^ *,//' file.csv`

Comment: See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: @anubhava Thanks a lot.  Possible to add it as an answer? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed -i '' 's/^[[:blank:]]*,//' file.csv
```

`^[[:blank:]]*,` will match comma at line start with optional whitespaces before comma.

Answer (score 2):

try this;

```
sed 's/^,//' csvFile > newCSVfile
```

Ex;

```
user@host:/tmp$ echo ',"a","b","c"' | sed 's/^,//'
"a","b","c"
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use "g" flag in sed, it will help you in removing only first matching ","

```
echo ',"a","b","c"' | sed 's/^,//'
```

For file :

```
sed -i.bak 's/^,//' infile.log
```